# SQL: Finding DB entry that ends a given string

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to perform a SQL request to extract some data. I'm not sure if it's possible, and if so, I don't know how to do it. I believe an example is better to demonstrate what I'd like to do.

Lets assume a very simple table:

```
--------------------------
| ID | domain            |
--------------------------
| 1  | example.com       |
--------------------------
| 2  | stackoverflow.com |
--------------------------
```

I would like to retrieve the entry whose `domain` **ends** a specified string.

If user input were `www.example.com`, what request could I perform so the entry whose `domain` is `example.com` would be retrieved?

The string `www.example.com` is ended by the string `example.com`, that means I can't use `% LIKE` SQL construct, because I'm looking for a substring of the predicate.

Here is a potential dirty workaround to make it clearer:

```
user_input = "www.stackoverflow.com"
for domain in get_all_domains_from_db():
    if user_input.endswith(domain):
        print "It's this one!"
```

Ps: Let me know if something isn't clear.

Comment: Just wondering if you have www.example.com can't you trim out www. and use just example.com as your input. I mean to say is that always the case?

Comment: @AJP Unfortunately it won't always be the case. User input could be `static.srv1.example.com` or `bla.bli.meh.stackoverflow.com`; therefore i can't trim safely for sure.

Comment: Use clientside ,javascript, or serverside,PHP, to remove unwanted chars not SQL

Comment: which programming language you're using either java,php,.net?

Comment: @davidstrachan , Meeran : Client side is Javascript, server side is Python. Filtering input, either server or client side, could be a decent alternative solution, but I would prefer that the filtering and search happen on the database -- if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will resolve your problem.

```
select * from table_name where :userParam like CONCAT('%', domain)
```

:userparam will be 'www.example.com'

Comment: Yeah ! This is exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you do this as:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE domain LIKE '%example.com'
```

I'd advise you to **never** fetch and iterate over all the records in the database. That's a technique that only works for trivial amounts of data. Always use the database to do filtering for you.

Comment: Yep I know, I don't use this code, it's to demonstrate what I wanna do. However, the user input in my case in `www.example.com` and I want to retrieve the row `example.com`, which means I cannot have `%example.com` in my request, because the user input is `www.example.com`. I'm not sure if I make sense?

Comment: Why not? `example.com` matches `%example.com` where `%` means simply "zero or more characters". See the reference for [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like).

Comment: Because I can't write `%example.com` in my query. User input is the filter and it is `www.example.com`, which means I could write something like: `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE domain LIKE '%www.example.com'`, but this wouldn't match `example.com`.

Comment: Ah, right, I missed that. That's a problem with your user input then. The best way to handle this is to extract the domain name using the [public suffix list](http://publicsuffix.org/) if you can find a library that reads that for the language you're using, or just strip off the `www.` part by default.

Comment: Yep, finding a library to handle domain name, and doing this client side would be an alternative solution.

Comment: As you note, TLDs like `.uk` have other components that make it impossible to do this without the full ruleset. You simply have to do this application-side to do it correctly.

Comment: Well, I guess it would work because user input would be something like `www.srv1.bla.co.uk`, and domain would then be `bla.co.uk`, so `bla.co.uk` is still a subset of `www.srv1.bla.co.uk`.

Answer (score 1):

What about the following:

```
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(domain, '.', -2) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_filter, '.', -2)
```

If your `domain` field is always just the domain itself (w/o any prefixes), then

```
WHERE domain = SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_filter, '.', -2)
```

This approach is shamelessly *borrowed* from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Comment: My `domain` field in database is always just the domain itself. However, what you suggest is true only if the TLD is not composed. `SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.mysql.co.uk', '.', -2);` wouldn't work. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

you could split the user input along the `.`s, and try shorter and shorter sequences.

some pythonlike pseudocode:

```
user_input = "www.stackoverflow.com"
split_domain = user_input.split('.')
query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE domain = ' + '.'.join(split_domain)
while db_returns_no_rows(query) and split_domain:
    del split_domain[0]
    query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE domain = ' + '.'.join(split_domain)
```

Comment: While I appreciate you're answer (and would've done something like that if I was in a hurry) this is kinda hacky :P. I'm looking for a cleaner solution, if possible. Thank you!